# MS Access- Rolling YTD calculation Sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Was trying to figure out how to implement YTD calculations in Access 2010 using SQL query.
Current table:

```
Property date_rec(mm/dd/yyyy) Revenue month1 year1

    A    01/01/2013            100       01 2013
    A    02/01/2013            50        02 2013
    B    01/01/2014            200       01 2014
    B    02/01/2014            300       02 2014
```

Desired output:

```
   Property date_rec   Revenue YTD_revenue
    A         01/01/2013 100     100
    A         02/01/2013 50      150
    B         01/01/2014 200     200
    B         02/01/2014 300     500
```

We have tried the below query but MS Access throws the error: 'you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression month1 as part of an aggregate function'

```
select test.property, test.date_rec, (select sum(test.revenue) 
                               from test a 
                              where a.month1<=b.month1 AND a.year1=b.year1) 
as revenue_ytd into new_table 
from test b
where a.date_rec=b.date_rec 
group by property, date_rec order by property, date_rec;
```

Can someone please help us debug the code or tell us if we're doing something wrong? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  You just need to include the year and month in the `group by` clause:

```
select b.property, b.date_rec,
       (select sum(a.revenue) 
        from test as a 
        where a.month1 <= b.month1 AND a.year1 = b.year1 and
              a.property = b.property
       ) as revenue_ytd
into new_table 
from test as b
group by property, date_rec, month1, year1
order by property, date_rec;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon. Thank for the reply. But it still shows the same error with the changes suggested

Comment: @user3111273 . . . I just fixed a bunch of other problems I didn't notice the first time.  Perhaps that will help -- or at least generate another error.

Comment: One question: Why did you add a.date_rec = b.date_rec within the subquery?

Comment: @user3111273 . . . Your query had that condition in the outer query (where it doesn't belong).  The inner query needs to make the properties the same -- I copied the logic without realizing it was about dates.

Comment: Worked like a charm Gordon... though it took a very long time to run but worked :) Thanks a ton!!!